# Reject request and remain on referring page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view which after a certain operation calls a new action in a different controller.
When this new action is loading its information, it may find out that the data is no longer valid (working against a 3rd party backend). 
In this case I want to reject the request and **remain** on the calling page (i.e. not reload/call the referrers action method again).

How may this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

you can write something in your controller action like

```
if(data not found)
{
    return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

if there is no url referral and you are typing url in browser's address bar it will throw null reference exception
**Edit:**
in case of username/password validation we use one ActionResult for HttpGet and one of HttpPost request

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    LoginViewModel model = new LoginViewModel();
    return View(model);//this will render the view for first time
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if(!ValidUser(model))
        ModelState.AddModelError("form0", "user name or password incorrect");
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       return RedirectToAction("Home", "Index");//return to success page if correct
    }
    return View(model);//if we got here we have errors so render same view with errors 
}
```

in your view you should use

```
<%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.UserName)%> with each field and
<%:Html.ValidationSummary()%> with your form
```

Comment: This will cause a call to the referrers action method again though

Comment: @user204884 don't u want to stay on calling page if some condition fails on current page?

Comment: (sorry I logged in with a different user...) Yes, but calling the referrers action again means reloading data there from the backend. Could this only be accomplished with client side validation?

Comment: i am afraid this may not be possible since you have to return an ActionResult object from each action method (or any of its subclass).

Comment: How does it usually work with validating username/passwords? On failure, do they reload the login page? What about ajax maybe?

Comment: Thanks. Based on that, I guess my only option is to perform a post to current page, load new data from model and then redirect to new. If it fails, then I can perform a partial view update which does nothing.